# Adjective defining a property of an object that is possessed by many of those objects

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word defining an object's property possessed by many similar objects? Something like this:

> Tommy bought a red balloon at the circus. Many kids have red balloons there. Hence ballon's color is <the word I am looking for>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of [*ubiquitous*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ubiquitous), which means that it is found everywhere.

> Every child had a red balloon. The color red was ubiquitous.

Answer (score 9):

One adjective would be [*common*](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/common):

> happening often; existing in large numbers or in many places
>
> - Jackson is a common English name.
> - Breast cancer is the most common form of cancer among women in this country.
> - Some birds which were once a common sight are now becoming rare.
> - a common spelling mistake
> - Allergies to milk are quite common in childhood.

So, because there are so many red balloons, Tommy's balloon color is *common*.

Comment: This is easily the best answer. "Common" connotes "many" in a way that most other suggestions (like "usual") connote "most" instead.

Comment: Depends on what the poster wants to communicate.  In fact, ubiquitous was the answer that first came to my mind, too.

Answer (score 2):

Words such as *typical*, *ordinary*, or *average* might be good options here.

Answer (score 0):

Red is the most *popular* colour?
Red is the most *commonplace* colour?
Red is the *usual* colour?
Red is the *norm*?
Red is the *conventional* colour?
Red is the *prevalent* colour?
Red is a *popular* colour?

Red is the *usual* colour?